# Few questions about socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets

I have a few questions with regards to socket programming over Telnet/TCP in C:

1. When I activate the client to access the program remotely it behaves normally however if I close down the terminal whilst the program is running, the last remote command issued decides to repeat itself until the program is terminated, how do is top this?
2. When my program reaches the socket code i.e. my declared function below i can no longer operate my program manually/locally even if I don't have the client open. I have had a Google with this issue and the top result seems to be to do with the accept socket command blocking access. Note: I have tried to use non blocking sockets but still no luck. Also note that I would like my program to be able to be operated both manually/locally simultaneously even when the remote terminal is activated, and if possible if the program is controlled manually when the remote terminal is up to reflect the change on the remote terminal.
3. And finally, I would like the ability to be able to type a word or phrase to activate a command rather than just a single character. If I enter a word instead of a character I get a multi character error and if I try double quotes it doesn't seem to respond to anything despite successfully compiling. From what I have heard you can use double quotes if you are programming in C++ but not C, however i have heard it is possible to use words to issue commands in C.

I have posted my socket code below, I know the while(1) loop is a issue but this is the only thing currently preventing it from closing the connection. Also note that the remotecommand function is declared in my main program in an infinite loop but when ran none of the code after the declared function is ran despite closing the connection.

```
void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
}

return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}



int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
int rc;
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
socklen_t sin_size;
struct sigaction sa;
int yes=1;
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int rv;
char recv_client_msg[100];


memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}

// loop throui_pgh all the results and bind to the first we can
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->arotocol)) == -1) {
        perror("server: socket");
        continue;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
            sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("server: bind");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if (p == NULL)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    return 2;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
}

sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
}

    int RemoteCommand(){  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
    return(-1);  
    }
    //fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    //fcntl(new_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
    close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
    if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
    perror("send");         

while(1) 
 {
   rc = read(new_fd, recv_client_msg, sizeof(recv_client_msg));
   if(write(new_fd,recv_client_msg, rc) <0 ) { printf("error writing to         stream socket\n"); }
   if(recv_client_msg[0]=='1') {commandSwitch(1,1);}
   if(recv_client_msg[0]=='2') {commandSwitch(1,2);}
   if(recv_client_msg[0]=='3') {commandSwitch(2,1);}
   if(recv_client_msg[0]=='4') {commandSwitch(2,2);}    
 }
    close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    return(0);
}   
//end of socket setup
```

This is my first use of sockets so please try and explain in detail what you mean should someone have a solution.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually check what `read` returns. It returns `-1` on error, and `0` when the connection was gracefully closed.

Since you don't check that, you will not notice that the connection have been closed, or any errors, and just try to receive and receive and receive, with nothing happening and using the same data over and over again.

---

Example of proper handling:

```
rc = read(...);

// At this point, we don't know if we have actually received anything

if (rc <= 0)
{
    if (rc == 0)
        printf("Connection closed in a nice way by the other end\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading: %s\n", strerror(errno));

    // Do note that not *all* errors are actually fatal,
    // For example: If you have non-blocking sockets then you
    // could have `errno == EWOULDBLOCK` and that's okay, and
    // means you should try to receive again in a little while

    break;  // Break out of loop, let the connection be closed
}

// Now we *know* we have received something, process the data received
// To be more precise, we have received `rc` byes of data
```

Comment: on another version i wrote                                             if(recv_client_msg[0]=='x') {break;}   this successfully closes the connection when x is pressed, but what I'm  referring to is if someone closes the client with the red x at the top right rather than properly. That's when it repeats the last entered command repeatedly. Until I Cltrl + C the program

Comment: @DA93 Yes, and that's when you need to check what `read` *returns*, you need to check what `rc` is. If `rc` is negative there's an error on the connection, if `rc` is zero then the connection was gracefully closed.

Comment: @DA93 Also, please read [the `read` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Comment: is this just for troubleshooting? where would i check rc? I suspect the error is due to the infinite while loop. How do i make it constantly check for a key press when it isn't in an infinite loop?                                                                                                                    But my biggest question that is driving me mental is how do I operate the program both manually and locally simultaneously, so if i'm connected remotely with the client and make a local change, the client recognises the change and reflects it on the client terminal. 1/2

Comment: and since i'm new to sockets can you please explain how or why even after closing the connection the socket remains accepted so I cant make a local change? thanks 2/2

Comment: ok doke, thankyou JP, but can you confirm/deny if it is possible to still operate my program using the client without disabling local use, currently with a google it seems that the accept seems to always block in some way..

Comment: @DA93 If you have blocking sockets, then `accept` will block until there is a new connection. If you want to continue your program without blocking, search for **non-blocking sockets** or **socket select function**.

Comment: yes, i have already looked into non-blocking sockets thats why i have the header file and the two lines(that are currently commented out). when testing I didn't notice a difference, maybe its because the while loop is still present? however if i take out the while loop and comment out the close and exit so it doesn't terminate. when running the client then it doesn't even recognise key presses :S

Comment: @DA93 Making the listening socket non-blocking *after* you call `accept` will not do anything for the `accept` call. Just do it once after the socket was created.

Comment: ?..  i have put them in and a accept error repeats itself, i'm assuming that means a good thing that it is sucessfully non blocking, however still can't do anything locally when my code reaches the declared function

Comment: You have to check which interface you actually bind to, it might be the internal interface and not the catch-all interface (which wont come up in a `getaddrinfo` call). Search for `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: No luck. Could you please try and give me a straight up answer to my problem and then if it works then explain. Eg c and p my code and alter it to try an meet my above criteria, I will be greatful

Comment: @JoachimPileborg has alreadly provided a good answer to your original question.  You should accept it an move on.  If you find that you have new and different problems, you should, (after progressing you own debugging), post a new question with your new code.  Asking SO contributors to 'fix my network code so that it works and c/p it in' is annoying.  What if it's some problem with your environment only?  Sorry, but YOU have to do the testing and debugging.

Comment: OK, THEN, you tell me in what way he resolved any of my questions and specifically which one? they look like debugs to me not solutions. such as how do i replace the while loop so the rest of the program will still run as well?

Comment: @DA93 The code I show is the way to handle connections that closes or that have errors, i.e. the first question you ask.

Comment: Ok thanks very much, but do you have a solution for number two? This is my most important point stopping me proceeding properly with my project, I have looked up select sockets too but I don't quite get that either, when I compare that code to select code its 90% the same

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have also tried an example using non-block functions and select() functions but they both seem to have the same outcome when it comes to solving number 2: they both accept the commands but accept still appears to block the connection and even if i break out that loop the code after the declared function still doesn't execute. Only difference i can see is with non blocking sockets, it give me a warning saying they are non blocking and then when i establish a connection, an error repeats itself, the error stops when a command is issuedand then resumes when the command stops.